# Restful URL in CQ5

Tags: rest, aem

Currently, all our pages in CQ5 exist as static content pages.
eg.

```
/products/categoryOne/productOne.html
/products/categoryOne/productTwo.html
```

I'd like to be able to develop this as a more dynamic solution, where I can do something along the lines of

```
/products/[dynamicCategory]/[dynamicProductName].html
```

Which I would then populate with the appropriate information into the template by calling an external RESTful service. Is this possible, in CQ5? It seems like I would need an actual CQ5 page for every category/product combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your requirement is to display dynamic category and product information on a single instance of a "products" page without a querystring?

The apache sling [url decomposition description](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/url-decomposition.html) contains two very simple approaches to solve that. 
Either selectors or a suffix path. Both approaches can contain your identifiers for dynamic data.

Using selectors to identify the category and product id/name, the URL scheme for this approach looks as follows.

```
/products.[dynamicCategory].[dynamicProductName].html
```

Using a suffix path the URL scheme would look as follows:

```
/products.html/[dynamicCategory]/[dynamicProductName]
```

With both approaches you just have one instance of a products page, which is then responsible for processing the values of the present selectors or suffix path an to retrieve the external data.